# How to resolve gulp dependencies while creating a NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, dependencies

I have a nodeJs application(demo) which using [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) package to take command line argument and using [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) for

1. build
2. docs
3. test
4. coverage

This functionality is working fine but Now I need to move this application as a **NPM Package**.

Changes are done according to according NPM Package but when I install this as NPM package `npm install ../demo/` from local location.

It asks for following gulp dependencies: -

1. Cannot find module `gulp`
2. Cannot find module `gulp-load-plugins`
3. Cannot find module `del`
4. Cannot find module `gulp-plumber`
5. Cannot find module `gulp-eslint`
6. Cannot find module `babel-eslint`
7. Cannot find module `gulp-debug`
8. Cannot find module `gulp-sourcemaps`
9. Cannot find module `gulp-babel`

Every time I go back to the npm package(which i created) directory and run the command which occurs as an error like `npm install gulp --save-dev` and `npm install del --save-dev` and so on.

I also defined these dependencies in package.json but it is still throwing errors.

Is there any way to resolve this issue.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md",
  "keywords": [],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build",
    "coverage": "gulp coverage",
    "docs": "gulp docs",
    "prepublish": "gulp build",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.6.1",
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "mustache": "^2.2.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.0",
    "wrench": "^1.5.8",
    "ms": "^0.7.1"
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^2.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-nodejs-lts": "^1.2.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "esdoc-es7-plugin": "^0.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-babel-istanbul": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-esdoc": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-inject-modules": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "btoa": "^1.1.2",
    "superagent": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.0.0"
  }
}
```

I put all the things in `dependencies`. I tried that way but having same problem.

```
npm install ../demo/
npm WARN package.json demo_project@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json demo_project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json demo_project@1.0.0 No README data

> demo@0.0.1 prepublish /work/demo
> gulp build

[16:53:33] Local gulp not found in ~/work/demo
[16:53:33] Try running: npm install gulp
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) doesn't mention it, `npm install folder` only installs `dependencies` and not `devDependencies`. This may be a little bit confusing as running `npm install` inside the package folder installs **both** `dependencies`and `devDependencies`.

So try to install `gulp`and all the rest as `npm install --save gulp` (not 
`--save-dev`)

---

**UPDATE:** after adding `package.json`:

everything under `devDependencies` in your `package.json` should be under `dependencies`:

```json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md",
  "keywords": [],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp build",
    "coverage": "gulp coverage",
    "docs": "gulp docs",
    "prepublish": "gulp build",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.6.1",
    "commander": "^2.9.0",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "mustache": "^2.2.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.0",
    "wrench": "^1.5.8",
    "ms": "^0.7.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^2.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-nodejs-lts": "^1.2.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "esdoc-es7-plugin": "^0.0.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-babel-istanbul": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-esdoc": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-inject-modules": "^0.1.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "sinon": "^1.17.4",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "btoa": "^1.1.2",
    "superagent": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#before-publishing-make-sure-your-package-installs-and-works) I testing npm package before publish. I also defines above dependencies in package.json file.

Comment: But you are installing them as `devDependencies` and not normal **`dependencies`**. The difference is using the `--save-dev` instead of using `--save` flag with `npm install`.

Comment: I do not want to install them. what I want is whenever i do `npm install ../demo/`. All the dependencies will be installed automatically.

Comment: Add your `package.json`and I will show it to you what I mean.

Comment: Added `package.json`

Comment: Do you see the difference between `dependencies` and `devDependencies`?

Comment: Added all the things in `dependencies` but still got error. Updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120229/discussion-between-yan-foto-and-spunkylive).